# when does $\mu(dx) = f(x) dx $, where $\mu \in \mathcal M (\mathbb T) $

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis

I am currently reading the book Classical and Multilinear Harmonic Analysis.
However, I got stuck by the exercise 1.2 where it ask me to show that  $$\mu(dx) = f(x) dx $$ for some $f \in C(\mathbb T)$, when $\mu \in \mathcal M (\mathbb T)  $ and $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z}\lvert\hat{\mu} (n)\lvert \lt\infty \  \ (*) $$  My initial feeling is that this summation tells me that the absolute value of fourier series associated with $\mu$ is bounded and this will lead to the existence of f that is continuous on $C(\mathbb T)$ such that for any measurable subset $\mathbf E$ in $\mathbb T $, $\mu(\mathbf E) = f(x)m(\mathbf E)$, where $m$ is the lebesgue on $\mathbb R$. So , for me it looks like if a complex borel measure satisfy the property $(*)$ then there exists a "density" function  such that $$\hat{\mu} (n)= \int_{\mathbb T} e^{-2\pi i x} \mu(dx) = \int_{\mathbb T} e^{-2\pi i x} f(x)dx = \hat{f}(n)$$ I am not sure how to prove this equality, is there anyone can give me some hint about it.

Comment: Both of your integrals over $\mathbb{T}$ need an "$n$" in them somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $f(x):=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z} e^{-2\pi i n x}\hat\mu(n)$ for $x\in\Bbb T$. Then $f$ is continuous because of (*), and $\int_{\Bbb T}f(x)e^{2\pi i nx}\,dx=\hat\mu(n)$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$. It follows that the Fourier coefficients of the measure $\mu(dx)-f(x)\,dx$ are all $0$; therefore $\mu(dx)-f(x)\,dx$ is the zero measure, so $\mu(dx)=f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried your method but I can't show that $\int_{\mathbb T} f(X) e^{2\pi i nx} dx = \hat \mu(n)$

Comment: I fixed the problem, I forgot to use the orthogonality relation. Thanks anyway !